# How to change text colour and font weight if checkbox is checked with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Make the text saying “I have read and agree to the terms and conditions” change to the colour black and remove the bold if the user checks the terms and conditions checkbox, and return to the original formatting if they uncheck the checkbox

Code from php file

```
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id='termsText'>I have read and agree to the terms and conditions <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
```

what should be the javascript file code should be by using document.getElementById

[image]

Comment: Hello. Have you tried out something yet? Please share here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your code but I am supposing what you need is something like this.

you gonna have your HTML like this

```
    <p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id='termsText'>
I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
<input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
```

And your javascript should be something like this.

```
var input1=document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0];
input1.onclick=function(){
    if(input1.checked){
    document.getElementById('termsText').style="color:black; font-weight: bold;";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('termsText').style="color:red; font-weight: bold;";
  }

}
```